# setInterval not working with long intervals in MS

Tags: javascript

I'm using a `setInterval()` with Node, however I'm running into an odd issue. For some reason, when I try to set an interval of `9000000`, it doesn't work. I am trying to have a task execute every 86400000 milliseconds (24 hours).

The below works:

```
setInterval(() => {console.log('hello')}, 1000)
```

However, this does not -- it does not even print `hello` the first one time, as it should when being called:

```
setInterval(() => {console.log('hello')}, 900000000)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you waited the *250 hours* for the interval to pass?

Comment: setInterval does not run the callback instantly. The loop starts with the waiting time.

Answer (score 3):

The interval is stored as a 32-bit int, so the maximum value you should be able to use is 2,147,483,647, or `Math.pow(2, 31) - 1`

This works out to **around [25 days / 596 hours]**. In other words, your value should work fine

[Here is the relevant part of the Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval#Return_value)

Here's an example:

```js
// This is the maximum value you can wait, so it will actually wait this long
setInterval(() => console.log('You will not see me'), Math.pow(2, 31) - 1)

// This is 1 above the maximum value, so it overflows to 0
setInterval(() => console.log('Overflow'), Math.pow(2, 31))
```

Comment: you are true... let's come back in around ten days when the set interval will complete and trigger

Comment: You inspired a quick little edit, so thank you - Don't fancy keeping this page open long enough to double check my work this time...